# Need for message text and time retrieved from Firebase to be of different sizes, but end up in same TextView

Tags: java, android

I am creating a chat app and each individual message should have its respective text and time. The issue is that I want the message time to be a different size than the message text, but they should each fall into the same spot in the layout with their respective background.

At first I created the time below the message in the xml file as you can see in the picture, but I don't like it there. I want it inside of the message background. So programmatically I am trying to retrieve and change the size of the message time, but both should go in the same `holder.show_message`, but both text and time are coming back the same size.

From the information I have found online I have been doing it like this, but this isn't giving me the desired result. The time below the message I am going to get rid of, just wanted to show the text format of how I want the time *Inside* of the message to be.

**[image]MessageAdapter**

```
holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage() + "\n" + String.format(chat.getTime(), TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10));
        if (imageurl.equals("default")) {
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }
```

**chat_item_right**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Okay so let's start experimenting"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/show_message"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/show_message"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="12:26" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_seen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/show_message"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you create inside your item layout two TextViews and set their sizes there?

Comment: @Izak well I did do that at first. How can I change the xml to make the xml code so the time goes inside of the show_message? I tried it before, but my app crashed. I uploaded the xml code. And is there no way to do it programmatically? Change the size of the text of the time? Why isn't the code in the holder giving me the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning your text message background for the `show_message TextView`, surround your `msg TextView` and your `date TextView` with a container view (in my example `LinearLayout`) and set the background of `"@drawable/background_right"` on that container.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_right">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Okay so let's start experimenting"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="12:26" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_seen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay perfect man, thanks for the help. Works fine. Didn't think of the container solution. Thanks!!

Comment: If the answer helped, can you select the checkmark next to my answer as the correct answer?